# Excel VLOOKUP from multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am looking for a VLOOKUP style function that matches multiple criteria from a table of information. Easier to explain with examples. Imagine a database like this in a sheet called `data`,

```
  A    B    C    D    E
1     UK   EU   PL   FR
2 P1  10   10   20   20
3 P2  15   15   25   25
4 P3  30   30   40   40
```

And a list of values with desired outcome such as,

```
      A   B            C
1    P1  UK   =*should return 10*
2    P1  EU   =*should return 10*
3    P3  PL   =*should return 40*
4    P2  UK   =*should return 15*
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$4,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1,0),0)
```

(For details see [TechOnTheNet](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/2d_lookup.php).)

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you so much!